# Unable to connect to LDAP in MVC(without using active directory)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ldap

I want to connect to LDAP server using my MVC application.I dont want to use active directory.
Here is my post method when I get usename and password from user:

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(Login model, string returnUrl)
        {
            string pwd = model.password;
            System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 hs = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
            byte[] db = hs.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd));
            string result = Convert.ToBase64String(db);
            var BuildServerName = new StringBuilder();
            BuildServerName.Append("172.16.1.98");


        // setup an ldapconnection to that endpoint
        var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(BuildServerName.ToString());

        // it looks like you have an administrative account to bind with, so use that here
        var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(model.username, result, "dc=mnit,dc=ac,dc=in");

        // set the following to true if it's over ssl (636), if not just set it to false

        ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };

        // now set your auth type - I typically use 'negotiate' over LDAPS, and `simple` over LDAP
        // for this example we'll just say you're not using LDAPS
        ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;

        ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
        ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
```

It throws an error at `ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);` which is: The distinguished name contains invalid syntax. What should I do in this.
When I change `BuildServerName.Append("172.16.1.98");` to `BuildServerName.Append("LDAP://172.16.1.98");` it returns error

> The LDAP server is unavailable.

at `ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);`. Is there any other way to connect and check username and password through ldap

Comment: what's the value of model.username in your failed attempts?

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895562/validate-user-with-ldap-network-credential-in-net-mvc it may help

Comment: Its the value that the user enters.For Eg if username : abc101 and password : qwe123. then model.username value will be abc101 and model.password value will be qwe123

Comment: You may need to set the domain on the network credentials as well.