# dot net mvc 4, user authentication against LDAP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ldap

I'm new to dot net and I have tried a lot of options and still not able to authenticate a user against LDAP.
I have a web form where user should enter his login and password.
My ldap server is LDAPS://aaa.bbb.CCC.com
DN is OU=People, O=CCC

Can someone provide me what should I add to webconfig to make the ldap authentication working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LDAP Authentication in ASP.Net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401667/ldap-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I have followed the link suggested by you but I keep on getting following error:  
  
Parser Error Message: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.