# LDAP implementation on MVC4 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ldap, authorize

I am new on ASP.net MVC, I have this controller that uses Windows authentication (`xxxxDMZ\username`, password):

```
[Authorize]
public class ExController : Controller
{ 
    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        ViewBag.user = User.Identity.Name;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now I need to use a different domain (`xxxx\username`, password) to access this controller.

web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>       
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="GridMvc" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
```

Current IIS 7.5 configuration:
Windows Authentication Enabled(enabled providers: Negotiate, NTLM), Anonymous Authentication Enabled

**Notes:**

- the website is hosted in server that can be accessed via RDC by using
  `xxxDMZ\username`.
- `xxxDMZ\username` and `xxx\username` is totally different accounts.
- when the user login to windows, he uses this account `xxx\username`.
- I want users to browse the website without using credentials, I only need them to use credentials(xxxx\username, password) when trying to access the controller mentioned above.
- My problem is not all (xxxx\username, password) users have (**xxxxDMZ**\username, password) accounts.

Comment: How is this related to LDAP? is it an option to let the application pool that runs your website run under the account that you want?

Comment: Well I don't know, I got that from an answer from my previous post regarding the same issue: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384262/adding-asp-net-impersonation-users-of-specific-domain-to-windows-authentication?noredirect=1#comment52639696_32384262).

Comment: Are you hosting your site in IIS? what are the settings for IIS authentication? Is it windows authentication? Did you enable ASP.NET impersonation in IIS authentication? do you want this code to execute under the windows account of the user that is viewing the site?

Comment: Yes I am hosting it on IIS 7.5. the authentications are now set for both windows authentication and anonymous authentication. ASP.NET impersonation is not enabled. Yes I want this code to be executed under the windows account of the user

Comment: Why do you need to enable anonymous authentication? If you don't need it, disable it. Enable ASP.NET impersonation and then test.

Comment: Another question: why do you need to run the code under the user account? To restrict access to windows resources? Another question: do you want this site to be accessible from the internet or just the local intranet?

Comment: I am not sure why anonymous authentication is enabled because I didn't create the website, it just got transferred to me but I think so users can access other parts of the website without the need of using credentials. I don't know how to implement ASP.net impersonation as I couldn't find any useful examples to my case

Comment: I need to run that controller under the user's windows account so I can capture their ID as there will be some kind of form to create records so I want to be able to see the ID of that user.

Comment: Doesn't `User.Identity.Name` currently give you what you want? even without any impersonation?

Comment: I want it only to be accessed by the local intranet.

Comment: User.Identity.Name is currently giving me the DMZ account of the user. so if the user doesn't have DMZ account, won't be able to access the page.

Comment: When the user uses your application, is he logged in to windows using his DMZ account?

Comment: No, he's logged in using xxxx acount.

Comment: He only needs DMZ account to access windows server remotely

Comment: Then why does User.Identity.Name give you a DMZ account? can you explain the environment a little bit?

Comment: Sure! so the website is hosted on windows server that can be accessed by the DMZ account, User.Identity.Name doesn't return anything if it's used in any part of the website that doesn't require a login([Authorize] part). in web.config  <system.web><authentication mode="Windows" /><membership><providers><clear /> </providers> </membership>  </system.web>

Comment: Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: So, the user logins into his station use the normal xxxx account? and then he connects remotely to another DMZ domain? How? Via RDC?  In the DMZ domain, is there a display name attribute on the user objects (in Active Directory I assume) that might satisfy your requirement?

Comment: Yes, the user logins into his station using the normal xxxx account, and if he wants to connect to the server which hosts the website then he'll need to use the DMZ account via RDC which is the same one needed to access that page, I don't quite understand your last question.

Comment: So it seems that you have a separate domain (Active Directory Domain) for DMZ. For each account, there exists an Active Directory object of type User. Maybe such object will contain information that might satisfy your requirement.

Comment: Earlier, you said that your goal is to capture the **ID** of the user, can you please explain more about this?

Comment: Yes, I need to capture the ID of the user which is the xxxx account so I can use it in later process.

Comment: But is there any link between xxxx\User1 and xxxxDMZ\User1?

Comment: They seem to be two different users from an active directory perspective

Comment: Actually there is no link between xxxx\User1 and xxxxDMZ\User1, totally different accounts.

Comment: Your best option might be to try to map between the two users using some shared piece of information. For example, is it always the same username? i.e., does xxxx\george map to xxxxDMZ\george? Maybe there is an active directory attribute that has the same value on both objects.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea but how can I verify that xxxx\george is george without knowing the password?

Comment: So when xxxx\george tries to access that page using his xxxx account and password, how will the controller check that he entered the correct password that belongs to xxxx\george?

Comment: From what I understand from you xxxx\george will never connect to the web site. It is xxxxDMZ\george that connects to the web site. This is a totally different user. The asp.net framework can assure you that xxxxDMZ\george is connecting to the web site via windows authentication. Can you use this information to say that it is xxxx\george that has opened the RDC session? for example, can we assume that only george has the password for xxxxDMZ\george?

Comment: Well, there isn't xxxxDMZ\george account. Only users that have DMZ account can access the server via RDP but they don't need to. Any xxxxDMZ account can access that authorized page even if they're logged in  with xxxx\george account.

Comment: So if xxxx\User1 logged into windows, and then he opened RDC, and then he specified the username/password for xxxxDMZ\User2, then he opened the web site from RDC, then you want your website to know that the original user is xxxx\User1?

Comment: How can he access RDC if he doesn't have DMZ account?

Comment: I think I am confused now. I know longer understand your problem. I suggest that you modify your question with all the details you provided in the comments + plus other information describing the exact scenario and environment that you want to support.

Comment: Thanks Yacoub for your comments!

Comment: You welcome. You might want to add in the question how some users have DMZ accounts and how do they login to such accounts using RDP. you might also want to describe the network environment (e.g. machines, which domains they are joined to)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that You need to configure an ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider for your authentication.

web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
      <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
      </authentication>
      <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
              <clear />
              <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
          </providers>
      </membership>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://primary.mydomain.local:389/DC=MyDomain,DC=Local" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Please refer to http://www.schiffhauer.com/mvc-5-and-active-directory-authentication/

Comment: Thanks Jesus for your answer!