# Integrate LDAP authentication into ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ldap

I have an application which uses individual authentication via SQL Server (register new user, change password etc) the code which handles it was generated completely by VS2019. Now I have to modify the authentication via LDAP and determine user privilege based on group membership. In this case I don't need the register and password change and more function only the login.

I have found some useful post but those were not clear for me.

I have methods which can authenticate the users and check the membership of groups but I don't know what is the easiest way to implement it into my existing application.

Comment: Read notes at bottom of following : https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/DNS_RPC_RECORD.html

Comment: *I have found some useful post but those were not clear for me.* which ones did you find and what was unclear?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401667/ldap-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc  - I have tried to modify based on this link. My concern is what should I do the current methods which handles the authentication so far. Can I use those for LDAP or completely rewrite?